# Should my "convenience" link that redirects to page 1 be a permanent or temporary redirect?

Tags: seo, redirects, url, 301-redirect

So, I have a simple blog. Included in my blog is tags. There are two ways to reach the first page of the posts belonging to a tag though. There is `/tags/foobar` and there is `/tags/foobar/1` (where foobar is the tag).

Right now I do a temporary redirect from `/tags/foobar` to `/tags/foobar/1`. Should I upgrade this to a permanent redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to leave the redirect there permanently, then yes, make it a permanent redirect.